# How to get nunit runners generated nunit-report.xml file in teardown

Tags: c#, xamarin, nunit, nunit-console

I currently run a suite of tests and in the TestFixtureTearDown I look for the "nunit-report.xml" and generate a webpage with the results. The problem is that this file will not be generated by nunit until after it has ran through the teardown. Is there any way that I can terminate nunit in code using c# in the tear down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NUnit generates it's XML output after the tests are finished. That makes sense, since the info to generate the report is not available till after the tests have all run.

What you may not be realizing is that your `TestFixtureTearDown` is **part of** your test. For example, even if everything was OK up to that point, the `TestFixtureTearDown` might throw an exception and give you an error result. And of course you may have more than one fixture that has still to run at the time `TestFixtureTearDown` completes for a particular fixture.

The above is true in all versions of NUnit. What you may do about it varies between NUnit V2 and NUnit 3. Sincde you use the term `TestFixtureTearDown`, I'll start by assuming an older version of NUnit...

In NUnit V2, the XML output is generated by the console runner itself. It's not available until after the runner exits. If you want to write code to generate a report from it, you have to write a separate program, which you run after the test completes.

In NUnit 3, the output is created by the engine but still on request of the console runner. The difference is that NUnit 3 supports extensions to the engine. You can write code as a report writer extension and invoke it from the command-line. With the proper extension, written by you, you might for example invoke NUnit with `nunit3-console mytest.dll --result:myreport.html;format:myhtml`

NUnit3 also gives you the ability to create a new output format based on an xslt transform if that sort of thing appeals to you. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Charlie I am using the older version of Nunit as I am writing tests in Xamarin UI Test and they only support version 2.6.4. I understand what the issue was but was hoping that there was some way to call the creation of the xml report file. If it is not possible then I will continue to run the code to generate my results page from the report after the suite has ran.